# How to customize the login page of ASP.NET Core web application with Angular Individual user account authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

(Environment: Visual Studio 2019 v16.4.3)

I create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application" with the following options

1. ASP.Net Core 3.1
2. Angular
3. Authentication of Individual User Account (with "Store user accounts in-app", the only option)

Running the application in Visual Studio and clicking Login in the browser will go to the following page.
https://localhost:44343/Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2Fauthentication%2Flogin

I cannot find the page in the Angular or ASP.NET Core code. How to customize the login page?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The template uses ASP.NET Core Identity for authenticating and storing users is combined with IdentityServer for implementing Open ID Connect.  So that you need to [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization) to modify the UI like login , register user ...

**If using Visual Studio :**

1. From Solution Explorer, right-click on the `project > Add > New Scaffolded Item`
2. From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select `Identity > Add`.
3. Choose Files to override ,For example , login related : Account\Login .
4. Select your data context class : `ApplicationDbContext` by default .
5. Click `Add` button.

**If using .net core CLI**

1. Create project using template : `dotnet new angular --auth Individual` and build the project .
2. If you have not previously installed the ASP.NET Core scaffolder, install it in terminal in vs code :

   `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`
3. Add required NuGet package references to the project :

   `dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

   `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
4. You can list the files that can be scaffolded with `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles`
5. Run the Identity scaffolder with the options you want , use `--files` to scaffold specific files ,use the correct fully qualified name for your DB context:

   `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc ProjectName.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"`

   If you run the Identity scaffolder without specifying the `--files` flag or the `--useDefaultUI` flag, all the available Identity UI pages will be created in your project.

Now if you want to modify the login UI , you can modify relevant page in `your project --> Areas-->Identity -->Pages-->Account -->Login.cshtml` page .

Comment: Great answer. I found it so counter intuitive that the files are not added by default. Especially because `MyProject\Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` determines the layout, differently from what the Angular SPA defined.

Comment: Agreed Great answer.  This same answer works if you use React SPA template.

Comment: This is great but for some reason, when I link to a custom `.css` file in the `_Layout.cshtml` it returns a 404 error.  All the `Identity` stylesheets and js are returned ok.

Comment: @Stephen Wilson  In a .Net Angular SPA app, a static file (e.g. css or js) can be linked to the Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml using the path relative to the ClientApp, not wwwroot. E.g  <script src="~/assets/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>   OR   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles.css" />