# Scaffold the login/register UI for the customized the ApplicationUser model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

(Environment: Visual Studio 2019 v16.4.3)

I create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application" with the following options

1. ASP.Net Core 3.1
2. Angular
3. Authentication of Individual User Account (with "Store user accounts in-app", the only option)
4. Update the class `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` under the Model (`ApplicatoinUser.cs`) folder and add a few properties like "FirstName", "LastName", etc.
5. Right click `project > Add > New Scaffolded Item`
6. From the left pane of the `Add Scaffold` dialog, select `Identity > Add`.
7. Now I can select with scaffolded items and the "Data context class".

However, the `User class` box is disabled. Should the `ApplicationUser` be in the list?

Comment: no, just replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser` in `startup`, `ApplicationDbContext` and scaffolded identity pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The user class selection is only enabled when creating a new DataContext class, it is disabled when selecting an existing data context class.
>
> When an existing data context class is chosen, the identity user associated with that data context class is used in scaffolding, because the data context is already setup to use the existing identity user:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

Reference : https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/839#issuecomment-413638895

Comment: I added some custom properties in `ApplicationUser` and updated the database. And added the Scaffolded pages. However, the custom properties are not shown in the Register page. Which UI page should be changed to fill these custom properties?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819170/5751404) and scaffold the Account/Register page